# Oracle SQL adding additional foreign keys

Tags: sql, oracle, entity

I am creating a logical model on Oracle SQL, however am having a bit of trouble. When I add a relationship between two entities, I'd expect Oracle to add the PK of the parent entity to the child entity, as a foreign key.

But instead of adding the already existing attribute as a FK, Oracle keeps adding an additional attribute with the same name but with a '_1' at the end of the name (e.g. teacher**_1** instead of using the already existing 'teacher' attribute)

Any ideas why this is the case?

Comment: Please include the SQL script that is doing this.

Comment: I apologize, I am rather new and unfamiliar oracle. How can I find the SQL script of a logical model?

Comment: What tool (and version) are you using to create the model? I'd guess either that tool is expecting you to remove (or never have added) the attributes (columns) as it wants to add them itself, or possibly there is a data type mismatch so it doesn't think they are related. The former seems more likely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using the data modeler, we assume when you add a foreign key, you haven’t already created the ID column.

So we create that for you.

Here’s what that looks like.

I draw the relationship.

[image]

You don’t want that.
You want it to use USER.USER_ID instead.

Click on the Column, and toggle it to USER_ID.

[image]

When I click ‘Apply’ or ‘OK’ – the generated column goes away.

[image]

If you don’t like being asked, you can set the default action when deleting the FK in the preferences: ‘Delete FK columns strategy’

**Tip: Draw from Parent to Child**
When I go to draw a FK, I always go from child to parent…I think backwards for some reason.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the info. Can I ask, where can I find the "foreign key properties" menu?

Comment: Double click on the relationship line in the diagram is the easiest way to get that

Comment: right. For some reason I don't see an option to toggle a column. I also don't see an associated columns section

Comment: My answer is for Oracle SQL Developer Data Modeler...is that what you're actually using?